# Order in closing resources

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, resources

Should I close the statement before the connection? And the resultset before the statement?
Or is it all the other way around?

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement st = null;
Resultset rs = null;

try {
    // Do stuff

} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Do stuff
}
finally {
    if (rs != null) rs.close();
    if (st != null) st.close();
    if (conn != null) conn.close();         
}
```

Or

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement st = null;
Resultset rs = null;

try {
    // Do stuff

} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Do stuff
}
finally {
    if (conn != null) conn.close();         
    if (st != null) st.close();
    if (rs != null) rs.close();
}
```

Comment: The rule is simple: close in the reverse order of opening. After closing the connection there will be no point in closing the statement.

Comment: Be careful: void close() throws SQLException, each close() must be in its own try/catch

Comment: In general, you should close resources as LIFO -- last-in-first-out.  So, the first thing you open (connection) should be the last thing closed.  The first method makes more sense.

Comment: Ideally a compliant JDBC driver, connection pool etc will close the `ResultSet`, `Statement` etc when you close the `Connection`; but unfortunately the reality is this doesn't always happen.

Comment: @Aubin or wrap the close in a method. if your program is terminating and it doesn't close a DB connection, it's not a big deal because when the JVM dies, so does that resource. If your program needs to continue running, it's an issue because your leaked resources will live on.

Answer (score 7):

Close the result set, then the statement, then the connection.

In other words, close everything down on a last-in-first-out basis.

Comment: AKA, also known as a `Stack`

Comment: @SnakeDoc AKA also known as also known as.

Comment: @Pescis I had to meet the minimum char amount ;-P

Comment: While this does answer the question, it does not help the OP become a better programmer nor gain more knowledge. OP, look into A.R.M. / Try-With-Resources Blocks for the proper way to do this in Modern Java (Java 7+). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 4):

You should close the resources in the reverse of the order you opened (as if these resources are on a stack).

With Java 7 try-with-resources, the ideal way is:

```
try (
   Connection conn = somethingThatGetsAConnection();
   Statement st = conn.createStatement();
   Resultset rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT something");
) {
    // Do stuff

} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

And Java will take care of it for you, and it will close the resource in the reverse order. See also the [Oracle tutorial on try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

> Note that the 'close' methods of resources are called in the *opposite* order of their creation.

You can find a more in-depth look at try-with-resources in the article [Better Resource Management with Java SE 7: Beyond Syntactic Sugar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html)

The Java Language Specification for Java 7 mentions in section [14.20.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

> Resources are initialized in left-to-right order. If a resource fails to initialize (that is, its initializer expression throws an exception), then all resources initialized so far by the `try`-with-resources statement are closed. If all resources initialize successfully, the `try` block executes as normal and then all non-null resources of the `try`-with-resources statement are closed.
>
> Resources are closed in the reverse order from that in which they were initialized. A resource is closed only if it initialized to a non-null value. An exception from the closing of one resource does not prevent the closing of other resources.

This can also be seen as a clear indication that the Java language designers consider closing resources in the reverse order they where allocated the norm.

Comment: @Aubin you are mistaken. Please remove your -1 from this answer too. ARM blocks order does not matter, the JVM takes care of it. This answers the OP's question better than the OP expected.

Comment: @Aubin Added a short mention of the reverse order, but I think StackOverflow isn't about always answering the exact question, but also about providing a better answer to the actual problem. And try-with-resources solves the question by removing the need to actually think about it.

Comment: Ok, NOW that's right, I've removed my downvote. A reference to the JLS will be nice to complete this answer.

Comment: @Aubin updated my answer, although in my reading of the JLS it explicitly mentions an exception in one close, does not prevent another close: "_An exception from the closing of one resource does not prevent the closing of other resources._" (of course it might mean that the specific resource you try to close hasn't been closed, but that also happens without try-with-resources

Answer (score 0):

`ResultSet`, `Statement` and then the `Connection`. The golden rule to JDBC connections and statements is to close in the *reverse* order of initiation or opening. In addition, the `ResultSet` is dependant on the execution of the `Statement` and the `Statement` is dependant on the `Connection` instance. Hence, the closing should occur in that order (ResultSet, Statement, Connection).

Answer (score 0):

The first example is the right way. The problem with any other order is that closing a `Statement` will automatically close any underlying `ResultSet` as well (and same may happen for a `Connection`) - so you need to close the one lowest in the hierarchy first.

The `close()` methods may throw a `SQLException`, as @aubin pointed out. One easy solution to this problem is to use [`DBUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html) `closeQuietly()` method for closing them - then you don't even need to null-check!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this with minimal effort, try using Java 7's new A.R.M. (Automatic Resource Management) Blocks, also known as Try-With-Resources.

```
try (Connection conn = null, Statement st = null, ResultSet rs = null){
    // Do stuff

} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

No ugly `Finally` or worrying about proper order, Java takes care of it for you.

Some more info regarding ARM/Try-With-Resources Blocks: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: What about the order of the close operations? It's the question and you don't answer it...

Comment: @Aubin it answers his question better. In ARM blocks Order does not matter, ARM blocks were invented to solve this exact problem. Please remove your -1

Comment: @SnakeDoc in ARM the close is called in reverse order of allocation

Comment: @Mark are you sure? I thought they were called to be closed in the order the JVM decided, meaning as soon as Connection conn is not used, it gets deallocated and GC'ed. meaning the programmer does not have to think about it.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I am going by that tutorial you also link to which mentions it explicitly (see the quote in my answer). AFAIK the compiler actually transforms a try-with-resources to a finally block with some (complex) exception handling; it is not much more than syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Mark I stand corrected. I thought it abstracted this more-so than it does. Thank you for the follow up.

Comment: See also this link on try-with-resources (especially the demystified section at then end): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html

Comment: Please add this link to your answer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: the order does not really matter as long as you close them individually.

---

From the official API specification on `close()` on class [`Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html), [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#close()) and [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()):

- For already closed resources, `close()` is a no-op:

  > Calling the method close on a Connection object that is already closed is a no-op.

  > Calling the method close on a Statement object that is already closed has no effect.

  > Calling the method close on a ResultSet object that is already closed is a no-op.
- Closing a resource of "higher order" closes their "derived" resources:

  > [Connection.close()] Releases this Connection object's database **and JDBC resources** immediately instead of waiting for them to be automatically reeased.

  > [Statement.close()] Note:When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

  You can try the following code to see if closing `Connection` also closes the other two resources:

  ```java
  // url, username, password and sql pre-defined

  Connection conn = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;

  try
  {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
  }
  catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  finally
  {
      if (conn != null)
      {
          System.out.println("conn is not null and I'm about to close it");

          try
          {
              conn.close();

              System.out.println(stmt != null && stmt.isClosed() ?
                                 "stmt is also closed" : "stmt is alive");

              System.out.println(rs != null && rs.isClosed() ?
                                 "rs is also closed" : "rs is alive");
          }
          catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      }
  }
  ```

Hence, say if we close them in this FIFO order: `Connection > Statement > ResultSet`:

```java
finally
{
    if (conn != null)
    {
        try { conn.close(); }
        catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
                                                        
    if (stmt != null)
    {
        try { stmt.close(); }
        catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
                                                        
    if (rs != null)
    {
        try { rs.close(); }
        catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

- If a "higher order" resource is successfully closed, its "derived" resources should've been closed as well

  - Calling `close()` on these already closed resources is a no-op but is fine as no exceptions are thrown
- If failed to be closed, its "derived" resources still have a chance to be closed

And you can also tell the similiar story for any other arrangements.